# julia: system image file "sys.ji" not found

Tags: linux, netbeans, julia

I am using the IDE Netbeans to code a project c++ under Linux(red hat 7). As I need to use some math functions, I try to embed the julia language into my c++ project.

Here is what I have done:

Download the Julia from [here](http://julialang.org/downloads/) (I choose this: Generic Linux binaries)

Set project properties: build-->C++ Complier-->Include Directories, add the include of Julia, something like this: ../myjulia/include/julia

Add the libraries: open a terminal and type the command line: sudo ln -s ../myjulia/lib/julia/libjulia.so /usr/lib/libjulia.so

Now if I run my project, I will get this error: System image file "../myproject/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/../lib/julia/sys.ji" not found

I hve checked this file: ../myjulia/lib/julia, in this file, there are all of the lib files (libjulia.so etc) and a file named "sys.ji".

Comment: Does `julia` run fine from a commandline?

Comment: @rickhg12hs  the problem has been solved. the problem is that we shouldn't use jl_init(); we should use jl_init_with_image("thePathOfSys.ji", "sys.ji");

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes -sorry. Will delete shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this issue after installing Julia v0.3.10 on a Windows machine and thought I'd post it in case it can help someone else.

When I ran `julia.exe` it gave me the error message listed above.

**Problem**:

I had created a system environment variable called `JULIA_HOME` and pointed it to the directory where Julia was installed.  Then, I added `%JULIA_HOME%\bin` to my `PATH`.

**Solution**:

I pointed `JULIA_HOME` to the ***\bin*** directory under the Julia install directory.  Then, I added `%JULIA_HOME%` to my `PATH`

Answer (score 2):

A "hello world" example from [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/embedding/)

Now we know that we need to setup the julia context with this code:

`jl_init(NULL);`

In fact this code may not setup a good context because the project can't find the system image file "sys.ji". So what we need to do is using another function instead of jl_init: `jl_init_with_image`. This function accept two parameters: the first is the path of the image file, the second is the name of the image file. So we should use it like this: `jl_init_with_image("/thePathOfSys.ji", "sys.ji");` One more thing: the path of sys.ji must be the absolute path.