# Compiling Julia embedded in C++ code

Tags: c++, julia

I'm trying to compile the following C++ code

```
#include <julia.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /* required: setup the julia context */
  jl_init(NULL);

  /* run julia commands */
  jl_eval_string("print(sqrt(2.0))");

  /* strongly recommended: notify julia that the
     program is about to terminate. this allows
     julia time to cleanup pending write requests
     and run all finalizers
  */
  jl_atexit_hook();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile the code using

```
gcc -I/usr/include/julia -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia -ljulia juliatest.cpp -o test
```

I get the following error-

```
juliatest.cpp:19:20:: error: too few arguments to function ‘void jl_atexit_hook(int)’
 jl_atexit_hook();
                ^
In file included from juliatest.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/julia/julia.h:1188:16: note: declared here
 DLLEXPORT void jl_atexit_hook(int status);
            ^
```

If I remove `jl_atexit_hook();` from the code, I get the following errors-

```
juliatest.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `jl_init_with_image'
juliatest.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `jl_eval_string'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the error message again, it tells you exactly what's wrong, and what the function signature is.

Comment: Even if I change it to  `jl_atexit_hook(1);`, I get the following errors-`juliatest_v1.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to jl_init_with_image`
`juliatest_v1.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to jl_eval_string`
`juliatest_v1.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to jl_atexit_hook`

Comment: The two errors are unrelated, the first was from the compiler because you forgot to pas an argument to a function, the second error is from the linker because you don't link with the library needed.

Comment: I am linking `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia -ljulia`. Do I have to include any other libraries?

Comment: The order you place libraries on the command line when building is important, place the library last.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/embedding/) you are trying to compile is a little bit outdated. As already mentioned you need to give an `exitcode` to the `jl_atexit_hook()`
 function. The linker message is about missing functions defined in libraries. To get rid of distribution details I downloaded and build the [tarball](http://julialang.org/downloads/). Now the example can be build using this makefile:

```
JULIA_DIR:=julia-0.4.2
JULIA_LIB:=$(JULIA_DIR)/usr/lib
JULIA_SRC:=$(JULIA_DIR)/src
JULIA_INC:=$(JULIA_DIR)/usr/include
CPPFLAGS:=-I$(JULIA_INC) -I$(JULIA_SRC) -I$(JULIA_SRC)/support
LDFLAGS:=-L$(JULIA_LIB)
LDLIBS=-ljulia
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH:=$(JULIA_LIB):$(JULIA_LIB)/julia

all: main

run: main
        @./main

clean:
    rm -f main
```

If you now type `make run` you will get the next error message about a wrong path the system image is searched in. As Thomas noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123505) the function jl_init() is creating a context that may fail in this case. We shall give the name and the path of the system image to the init function using `jl_init_with_image("julia-0.4.2/usr/lib/julia", "sys.so")` instead. This is an ugly hard coded path and can surely be replaced. But for getting started with this example and to get this problem known, it is enough. The corrected example is this:

```
#include <julia.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* required: setup the julia context */
  jl_init_with_image("julia-0.4.2/usr/lib/julia", "sys.so");

  /* run julia commands */
  jl_eval_string("print(sqrt(2.0))");

  /* strongly recommended: notify julia that the
     program is about to terminate. this allows
     julia time to cleanup pending write requests
     and run all finalizers
  */
  jl_atexit_hook(0);
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Running `make run` will now be a quite complicated way to calculate the square root of 2 :-)

Have fun.

Comment: Hi,@Kellerspeicher, what do you mean by "a little bit outdated"? Is there new ways to embed julia into C ?

Comment: Hi, with this "littel bit" I don't suppose a complete new way. The version that was the current one in December 2015 was 0,4,2. If you look at the declaration of jl_atexit_hook() you will find the need of an exitcode to be provided, The example (which can still be found in the documentation) is using a function signature (void) that changed in the meantime. "A little bit outdated" just means the need to adapt to the currently used signature, exactly what the compiler told.